# Porque requires e includes não conseguem adicionar arquivos que estão em diretórios acima do arquivo de chamada?

Tags: php, include, require

Percebi que `require` e `includes` não conseguem incluir arquivos que estão acima do diretório do arquivo de chamada. Porque isso ocorre?

Exemplo:

***Isso funciona:***

```
<?php require_once('inc/configs.php'); ?>
```

***Isso não funciona:***

```
<?php require_once('../template/header-home.php'); ?>
```

Ou seja, se você tiver que adicionar um arquivo que está acima do diretório do arquivo de chamada, dá erro falando que o arquivo não foi encontrado.

Comment: Você não está sabendo interpretar o erro que está recebendo. Se o caminho estivesse certo, funcionaria. Poste a mensagem de erro e a sua estrutura de pastas e arquivos para que possamos lhe ajudar melhor.

Comment: O PHP tem permissão de acesso ao caminho?

Comment: Provavelmente é a permissão do diretório. Faço isto muitas vezes, normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Dá para acessar sim!
é só saber a técnica simples.

Observe:
o aquivo que vou precisar é:

`C:\xampp\htdocs\slug.php`

O arquivo que vou usar para para incluir `"slug.php"` é:

`C:\xampp\htdocs\uploads\updoc.php`

No aquivo `"updoc.php"` vai o código simples:

```
<?php
include_once("\..\slug.php");
```

é muito simples acessar arquivos seja lá onde ele estiver.

Caso o arquivo "slug.php" esteja na pasta "xampp" vizinha da pasta "aploads"

No Windows seria:

```
<?php
include_once("\..\\xampp\slug.php");
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score -1):

Tente utilizar a constante [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.predefined.php):

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../template/header-home.php');
```